# Why memory is being modified without explicit modification

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, arguments

I've being wondering, is it some compiler related issue or regular C standard that some memory can be changed without request in the following code:

```
void f(int* p)
{
    printf("Value of p: 0x%p\n", p);
    printf("Address of p: 0x%p\n", &p);
}

void scratch()
{
    int num = 1; //Dummy value
    int* num_p;
    num_p = &num;

    f(num_p);

    printf("Value of num_p: 0x%p\n", num_p);
    printf("Address of num_p: 0x%p\n", &num_p);
}
```

And my output is:

```
Value of p: 0x009AFAC8
Address of p: 0x009AF9E8
Value of num_p: 0x009AFAC8
Address of num_p: 0x009AFABC
```

My question is: Why after `printf("Address of num_p: 0x%p\n", &num_p);` The address `0x009AF9E8` (that contained `0x009AFAC8`) changed to contain `0x009AFABC`? The embedded output doesn't show it, I inspected it when I opened the memory map to look back at pointer p. Is it some compiler adjustments due to the last `printf`, and it could use `0x009AF9E8` since the previous function doesn't use it anymore?

Comment: Nothing is being changed, and there are no compiler issues. You are printing things that have different values.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Read the question in the last paragraph. They are not asking about “observable” program behavior. They are asking about what they saw in the debugger.

Comment: Answers to any such questions is: "as-if rule". **Anything** is possible...probable...likely depending on the compiler optimization settings and its capabilities.

Comment: @IntToThe nothing *valid* has been changed. In the first case, you print the location of the copy of the pointer variable *on the stack* that was passed to the function. In the second case, you print its location in `main()`. After you have returned from the function, that location is no longer "owned." In the same way, you can't use a pointer to a local variable in a function, after returning from the function.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: No, that is not the answer to the question. OP is not asking what the C standard says or what is theoretically possible. OP used a debugger and is specifically asking about what happened in the specific implementation of their program. Things did happen, they observed it, and there are reasons for it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil well, I read this: "I've being wondering, is it [...] regular C standard that some memory can be changed without request" - and the answer is "yes, as-if rule." It didn't change the observable behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, after the function `f` returned, the program generated by the compiler reused the memory it was using for the parameter `p` for another purpose. Almost certainly, that memory is on the stack, and the program reused the stack space during the call to `printf`.

Comment: But why `0x009AF9E8` should be changed anyway to contain `0x009AFABC` if `0x009AFABC` is already stored somewhere else (the num_p's address)?

Comment: @IntToThe: You called `printf`, passing it various values, including 0x009AFABC. One possibility the value was passed in a processor register, and then `printf` set to work analyzing the format string and converting the value it was passed to hexadecimal for printing. While doing that work, it may have saved some of the values involved on the stack. So 0x009AFABC may have been put on the stack, and that place in the stack may have happened to be the address 0x009AF9E8.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, the values of the arguments are **copied** to the parameters. So when you pass `num_p` to `f`, the value is copied to the local `p`. Since they are different variables (the fact that they are pointer is inconsequential here), they have different addresses.

Comment: Yes I know that, and actually that wasn't my question.. I wanted to know why address of 'p' which is already obsolete is used to store the output of the last printf

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the function the prologue code allocates the space for the local variables.

When you return from the function the epilogue code frees this allocated memory.

As most implementations use the stack for the local variables, the next function called will reuse the same memory for its own local variables.